# Receive data intent opens second app when app is opened

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activitys.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When app is sterted, trying to share the text and app is launching but if open pervious app by android navigation button i see 2 my app exemplars. How to check if app is launched and reopen not open second at one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple answer:** you need to add

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

within your activity bracket (below android:name=".activitys.SplashScreen", for example)

**Better answer:** Go through this article to understand the different types of launch modes: https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe

**Best answer:** Read through the doc on tasks: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: Thank's a lot. It helps